# Intel S2600CP2J Motherboard with Noctua NH-D9DX i4 CPU Cooler + dual Xeon CPU E5-2670 Heat problems

Tags: cpu, motherboard, bios, fan, cooling

I have built a workstation from these components; All components used are brand new except the Motherboard and CPUs.

- Intel S2600CP2J Server Motherboard
- 2x Noctua NH-D9DX i4 Xeon Heatsink/fans
- 2x Xeon E5-2670 CPU's
- Enthoo Pro Case (PH-Es614P_WT)
- Corsair RM850x PSU
- 32 GB RAM
- 2x GTX 970's (MSI and Gigabyte)

[Workstation Build Image 1 (out of the case, no GTX970s)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAurc.jpg)

[Workstation Build Image 2 (in case, 2x GTX970's)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9TEB.jpg)

It is all working fine, except the CPUs are getting rather hot; they are going up to around 80/90c after a few minutes data processing on 100% load; I have been advised this is way to hot and they should be at around 60c.

The heatskinks and fans are connected and are spinning, but I cannot seem to find a way in the bios to get this to increase cooling.

The Motherboard is in the case and the case Fan Hub is connected to Sys_fan_7 on the MB (the only spare 4pin fan header). The CPU fans are connected to CPU_Fan_1 and CPU_Fan_2.

I have tried changing the limited options in the BIOS with no change; all there seems to be is an option for power or performance, but no related to CPU fans.

I have not updated the BIOS as I have been advised this could cause major issues if this fails, and have taken this advice as being a newbie system builder.

Additionally, someone else that had built this machine using the same parts as I, explained that after he updated the BIOS there was no drop in CPU temp; indeed as it now fully implemented the Turbo boost of the Xeon CPU's this infact increased CPU temp slightly.

Additionally I currently have two GTX970's in the workstation, which I have now removed to keep case and CPU temp down.

---

THE SOLUTION IS THE LAST POST DONE BY MYSELF - ALL FIXED NOW!

---

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer turned out to be..

Basically you had to run the SDR update, which in turn reset the FAN settings for a Non-Intel case which finally sorted out the CPU heat problems.

They are now running at a cool 60c when on 100% load across all 32 threads for weeks continuously processing data.

Answer (score 0):

This is my research for cooling system in PC, i hope it can resolve your problem :
http://www.slideshare.net/rizalpahlevi212/tfsc-technology
http://www.slideshare.net/rizalpahlevi212/tfsc-three-fan-smart-cooling-technology

Comment: Please DO NOT ADD YOUR SPAM LINKS TO SUPERUSER as answers!!!! Clearly 4G, the topic of your article, has nothing to do with CPU Cooling..